# Why is diazobenzene named so and not phenyl diazobenzene?

Tags: nomenclature

I have searched for this answer for a long while but haven't got it. Why is diazobenzene named so and not phenyl diazobenzene or something? The group with two bonded nitrogens is the diazo group. Why does the term diazobenzene refer to a molecule with two benzene rings?

Comment: Does it?$\;\!\!$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Diazo** group is $\ce{=N2}$.

Example: **diazomethane** $\ce{CH2=N2}$
(detailed structure: $\ce{H2C=N+=N- <-> H2C^{-}-N+\bond{#}N}$)

$\ce{-N=N-}$ is **azo** group.

Example: **azomethane** $\ce{CH3-N=N-CH3}$
However, preferred names are based on diazene $\ce{HN=NH}$, so better name for azomethane is **dimethyldiazene**.

So, note that “diazobenzene” does not exist. You obviously mean “**azobenzene**”, $\ce{C6H5-N=N-C6H5}$, whose preferred name is **diphenyldiazene**.

Comment: Actually my book had written diazobenzene, I think it was a misprint.

Comment: @Hema I wonder what the structure was.. there are similar compounds, **diazonium salts**, like $\ce{C6H5-N_{2}^{+} X^{-}}$

Comment: the structure in my book was of azobenzene